# Compute numpy.inner() over first (instead of last) axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra, inner-product

I'm trying to make a function like `numpy.inner`, but which sums over the **first** axis of both arrays instead of the last axis. Currently I'm using `tensordot` with `rollaxis`:

```
def inner1(a, b):
    return numpy.tensordot(numpy.rollaxis(a, 0, len(a.shape)), b, 1)
```

but I'm wondering: is there a better way? Perhaps one that doesn't require me to roll the axes?

I feel like `einsum` should make this possible, but I'm not sure how to use it here.
It seems to require me to hard-code the dimensionality of `a` and `b` when I specify the subscripts string, which I can't really do here because there is no particular requirement on the input dimensionality.

(Note: I *am* aware that there are performance implications to summing over the first axis instead of the last, but I'm ignoring them here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `np.tensordot(a, b, (0, 0))`.

Comment: Are you sure that works? This fails: `einsum('i...,i...->...', ones((1, 2)), ones((1, 3)))`

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do. In that case I think you want, `einsum('ij...,ik...->jk...',ones((1, 2)), ones((1, 3)))`.

Comment: I think you might have missed the point of the question? I can't control the input shapes. For all I know they might be `(1, 2, 3, 4)` and `(1, 5, 6, 7)`; the point is that all the dimensions except the first one should be irrelevant, so how would I use `einsum` when I don't know what the string should be?

Comment: I edited my answer, is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as pretty as the `tensordot` solution, but you can construct the `einsum` string from `ndim` of the inputs:

```
ll = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw'
astr = ll[0]+ll[1:a.ndim]+','+ll[0]+ll[a.ndim:a.ndim+b.ndim-1]
np.einsum(astr,a,b)
```

`np.einsum` lets you specify axes as lists rather than the string

```
np.einsum(a, [0]+range(1,a.ndim), b, [0]+range(a.ndim,a.ndim+b.ndim-1))
```

For a pair of 3d and 2d arrays, these produce:

```
 np.einsum('abc,ad', a, b)
 np.einsum(a, [0,1,2], b, [0,3])
```

`'...'` doesn't work here because that implies repeated axes (to the extent possible), where as you want unique axes (except for the 1st).

While messier to write, the `einsum` solution is faster than the `tensordot` one (3x faster for small test arrays).

---

Another option with `einsum` is to reshape the arrays, reducing the 'remaining' dimensions down to one.  This adds a bit of time to the calculation, but not a lot:

```
np.einsum('ij,ik',a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1), b.reshape(a.shape[0],-1)).reshape(a.shape[1:]+b.shape[1:])
```

Comment: I actually tried this myself and it turned out to be slower in my case -- but the problem that nags me more is the fact that there aren't enough letters in the alphabet to make this work in the general case. :P

Comment: I like the use of axes-lists; I hadn't seen that before. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: I add an approach using reshape.